# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append' (recursion function)

Tags: python, list, recursion, append, python-2.x

I'm trying to get all possible permutations of dice rolls. Below is my code.

```
def PrintAllPerms(n, arr, str_):
    if (n == 0):
        print str_
        arr.append(str_)
        return arr
    else:
        for i in ["1","2","3","4","5","6"]:
            str_ = str_ + i
            arr = PrintAllPerms(n-1,arr,str_)
            str_ = str_[:-1]

PrintAllPerms(2,[],"")
```

But I got following error after printing only this much.

```
PrintAllPerms(2,[],"")

11
12
13
14
15
16
21

<ipython-input-7-d03e70079ce2> in PrintAllPerms(n, arr, str_)
      2     if (n == 0):
      3         print str_
----> 4         arr.append(str_)
      5         return arr
      6     else:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Why does it print until 2,1 then?

And what is the correct to way to deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return `arr` in the else branch.

```
def PrintAllPerms(n, arr = [], str_ = ''):
    if n == 0:
        print(str_)
        arr.append(str_)
        return arr
    else:
        for i in ['1','2','3','4','5','6']:
            str_ = str_ + i
            arr = PrintAllPerms(n-1,arr,str_)
            str_ = str_[:-1]
        return arr

PrintAllPerms(2)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is due to the following line:

```
arr = PrintAllPerms(n-1,arr,str_)
```

Your `PrintAllPerms` function doesn't return anything if it takes the `else` path, and thus is treated as if it's returning `None`. So `arr` gets set to `None`.